# Create Button in rails app isn't working. Why won't it save to the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, belongs-to

So this may be a duplicate but I am having a lot of issues fixing it. I am new to rails so it could easily be something minor. I am making a workout log and am able to successfully save new data in the console but then when I go to the server it doesn't work.

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  has_many :workouts, dependent: :destroy

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i.freeze
  validates :name, :email, presence: true
  validates :email, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

Workout Model:

```
class Workout < ApplicationRecord
  validates :date, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :exercises, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc{ |attr| attr['name'].blank?}
end
```

Workout Controller (some methods removed):

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_login

  def new
    @workout = current_user.workouts.build(date: Date.today)
  end

  def create
    @workout = current_user.workouts.build(workout_params)
    if @workout.save
      redirect_to workouts_path, notice: 'Workout was successfully created.'
    else
      @errors = @workout.errors.full_messages
      redirect_to new_workout_path, notice: @errors
    end
  end

  private

  def workout_params
    params.fetch(:workout, {}).permit(:date, exercises_attributes: %i[_destroy id name reps weight weight_unit hours minutes seconds])
  end
end
```

_form (removed exercises nested form):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <%= form_with(model: @workout, local: true, authenticity_token: true) do |form| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
    <% if @workout.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@workout.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this workout from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
          <% @workout.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="container-fluid align-items-center">
      <form>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <%= form_for @workout do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <h2><%= f.label :date %></h2>
              <div style="font-size: 18pt"><%= f.date_field :date %></div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions" >
          <%= link_to "Create Workout", workouts_path, :method => :post %>
          <%= form.submit %>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Please let me know if you see anything off or have any suggestions on what to try. I did notice that I can save the workout if it is all done in the new method but not by clicking the button. I have two submit buttons because I was testing different things on each.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you want me to post more info.

Comment: Not sure if this is at all relevant, but it seems really odd that you have a manually-written `<form>...</form>` form tag. That's what `form_for` is for.

Comment: I took the form tags out like you said and it is a good tip but the form still isn't saving the data.

Comment: You should probably add the output from your server console to your question (by clicking on the `edit` link below the tags).

Comment: Wow jvillian you were right!!! I initially tried what you said by removing the form tags in the form partial but I also found that i had form tags around my new.html.erb. So it was a form rendering the partial of multiple forms.... After removing the excess form tags it went through fine. I knew it was going to be something stupid but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have manually added `<form>...</form>` tags to your html, here:

```
<form>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <%= form_for @workout do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <h2><%= f.label :date %></h2>
        <div style="font-size: 18pt"><%= f.date_field :date %></div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions" >
    <%= link_to "Create Workout", workouts_path, :method => :post %>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
</form>
```

Don't do that. `form_for` creates your form tags for you.